# Duplicates coming in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates, fluent-bit

I am finding some of the logs repeating twice in ES. While going through fluentbit doc, i read that i can use Generated_id for avoiding duplicates while retrying ES. I have a Question, the hashing will happen in which end, Fluentbit side or elastic search side. My concern is, if i have very large data in es, and if the hashing happens in es side it will cause a cost spike. So before implemeting Generated_id I want to confirm about the hashing.

Added Generate_ID, where is the hashing happening, in fluentbit cache?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing happens in a coordinating node is es side.Any node recevied the request is a coordinating node, and it will resend the request to the primary shard.

Hashing is very quick, you don't need to worry about it.

[image]